# having issues with session name and updating

Tags: php

When I use the session name in a SQL statement it comes back with no result but when I substitute it with the real username it comes back with a result.

```
$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")or die(mysql_error());
$results = (mysql_fetch_assoc($emails)) or die(mysql_error());
$email= $results['email'];
echo "$email";
die();
```

And also the update is not working.

```
if(array_key_exists('item', $_POST)){
    $items = $_POST['item'];

    //Loop through $_POST items, updating the database for each item
    foreach ($items as $item) { 
        $Pquantity = intval($item[0]); 
        $Pidno = intval($item[1]); 
        $queryreg = mysql_query("
            UPDATE repplac
                 SET Pquantity = {$Pquantity}
                 WHERE
                       Pidno = {$Pidno}
                 AND
                       Uname = '{$_SESSION['username']}'
        ");
```

Comment: hello [little bobby tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)!

Comment: Did you check the actual value of `$_SESSION['username']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the String stored in the SESSION[username] the same as it should be in the MYSQL Select statement. If they are, try using the SQL like this:

`$emails = mysql_query("SELECT reusers.email FROM reusers INNER JOIN repplac ON reusers.username = repplac.Uname AND reusers.username = '".$_SESSION['username']."')or die(mysql_error());`

And just a hint to prevent SQL Injection vulnerability: NEVER EVER insert data to your database which you get via GET or POST! Use intval() and mysql_real_escape_string() for strings to prevent attacks to your database!

Comment: Never ever use ANY unescaped values in your queries. Whenever possible, use prepared statements.